# Group and count NSArray Objects

Tags: ios, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an NSArray of objects. Each object has following properties/attributes `Name,Id,TYPE`. `Name` and `id` are dependent . i.e. if Id is 12345 and `Id` is AAAA then for all object with `Id` 12345 `Name` is always AAAA.

What I have is a particular `TYPE` say BedType. Now I want to consider only the objects of BedType , group them by `Id` and count how many objects belong to each group. What I want as output is the `Name` and the count for each group.

Answer (score 0):

You could fx create a dictionary where keys will be names and values will be counts of objects. Then you can iterate over your array and

```
NSMutableDictionary *countsByName = [@{} mutableCopy];

for(Object *object in myObjectArray){

    NSNumber *count = countsByName[object.name]
    if(count)
        countsByName[object.name] = @([count intValue] + 1);
    else countsByName[object.name] = @1;
}
```

You will need to make sure that you consider only object whose TYPE is BedType.